# What will be the database structure of following?

Tags: sql, database

What will be the database structure of following ?

```
Category1
|_Category2
|_Category3
   |_Category4
   |_Category5
      |_Category6
|_Category7
```

I mean that how can I store the above structure in database?

Comment: One of the following: adjecency list, materialized paths, nested sets - in that order.

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQLServer, MySQL, SQLite, etc) is this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! Try somethind like this:

```
|CategoryID|CategoryName|ParentCategoryID|
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 1        |Category1   | NULL           |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 2        |Category2   | 1              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 3        |Category3   | 1              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 4        |Category4   | 3              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

The root category, Category1 here, has no parent, hence the null in the parent column. All other categories will have the id of the parent category in the ParentCategoryID column. You can nest categories as deep as you like or need to.

Comment: Note that this is only effective if you have a DBMS that supports recursive queries (which most modern DBMS do...). Otherwise retrieving an arbitrary level of categories could be quite cumbersome

Comment: Note that SQLite and MySQL do **not** support recursive queries - from the OP's other questions, there is a strong chance that one of those two will be used.

Comment: @MarkBannister: if the OP will use SQLite or MySQL he'll have to do the recursion on the client side, never the less, the structure is still valid.

Comment: This might also work for you: http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/

Comment: @Mithrandir: It is valid, but not necessarily good; depending on the OP's requirements, there may be better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One table, say `category`, with the following fields:

```
ID, CategoryName, ParentCategoryID, Order
```

To store the data as:

```
ID  CategoryName  ParentCategoryID  Order
--  ------------  ----------------  -----
1   Category1     null              1 
2   Category2     1                 1 
3   Category3     1                 2 
4   Category4     3                 1 
5   Category5     3                 2 
6   Category6     5                 1 
7   Category7     1                 3
```